# Path does not fill SVG viewbox

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a simple SVG element with a single path inside. Here is the code and styling:

```css
path {
  fill: #e3e3e3;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: #666;
}
```

```html
<svg width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 100 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path d="M77.59516792876865,13.087133225865042L77.59529937957856,13.087104811439662L77.59539441616643,13.087086179305695L77.59577041164745,13.087012464557178L77.59608219429985,13.086963201220401L77.59648973969064,13.08689880685566L77.5967725795783,13.086855063260154L77.59746317305932,13.08674825710158L77.59815376654035,13.086641450943004L77.59823511433349,13.086628869814552L77.5988433527042,13.08652834743436L77.59898730507916,13.086504556703517L77.59953223379486,13.086411016103188L77.59954597102133,13.08640865801786L77.60022000641007,13.086287342668186L77.60090775953032,13.086163558351126L77.60130229989835,13.086092547535511L77.60159474130221,13.086035654778383L77.60164918398009,13.086025063275235L77.60171856079644,13.086010856062545L77.60210926181482,13.085939819999096L77.60227480950789,13.085881808595163L77.60269713904809,13.085733815415093L77.60289796667435,13.085673434761162L77.60292777672679,13.085702431614054L77.60295273784516,13.085726711808748L77.60312800559171,13.085563328862815L77.60319738240807,13.085591743288195L77.60354422985067,13.085549570080477L77.6039860872676,13.085495844602539L77.60423558980898,13.08554176011278L77.60425629171021,13.085545569846953L77.60422708041912,13.085719608202403L77.60373033144386,13.08578686652853L77.60323024511055,13.085854576722957L77.60322054698749,13.086048488879076L77.60319738240807,13.086511660309862L77.60331422757244,13.086557833751103L77.60333613604077,13.086568489160621L77.6034176910831,13.086592633156416L77.60342011850265,13.086593351782827L77.60355522072396,13.08663952522407L77.6035990376606,13.08665373243676L77.60381812234381,13.08672476850021L77.60407737255227,13.086806459973175L77.6040824192235,13.086808096306912L77.60411023525475,13.086817115382694L77.60412849231169,13.086579144570138L77.60416500642555,13.086621766208207L77.6045385867289,13.086651582763432L77.60523517549211,13.086707179584625L77.60558905686638,13.086735423909726L77.60557445122083,13.086952083903245L77.60557079980944,13.086998257344488L77.60556133761506,13.087078025965422L77.60554889134112,13.087182951109456L77.6055561941639,13.087239779960216L77.60556349698666,13.087335678645871L77.60564017662578,13.087495509788631L77.60566938791689,13.087562994048909L77.60571320485353,13.087648237325048L77.60579777682854,13.087686963700717L77.60643313665894,13.087977901490401L77.60702406154137,13.088248492061194L77.60707171427856,13.088259340588944L77.60719567787653,13.08828756189609L77.60729426598398,13.088308872715125L77.60775800509224,13.08839012469826L77.60788214321724,13.088411875007127L77.60797342850191,13.088429634022988L77.60843822034091,13.088548611025338L77.6086671966654,13.088607224181612L77.6084425025296,13.08901141186515L77.6081029654391,13.089622183079051L77.60776342834862,13.090232954292949L77.60742389125812,13.09084372550685L77.60714090670574,13.091352768033921L77.6070912716242,13.091458045163304L77.60679326641107,13.092090120953454L77.60649526119795,13.092722196743608L77.60619725598484,13.093354272533762L77.60612946575161,13.093498057150086L77.60610025446051,13.093565541410362L77.60605686336393,13.094029822971633L77.60605643752388,13.094034379429127L77.60608930022636,13.094130278114783L77.60667296967434,13.094234231847823L77.60736094712449,13.094356763229994L77.60738555126865,13.094361145320992L77.60758637889492,13.094396663352716L77.6080318510841,13.094467699416166L77.60803973759997,13.094450668959993L77.60821442165344,13.094073449264023L77.60849752228772,13.094073449264023L77.60900677792436,13.094073449264023L77.60900073594364,13.09426290122172L77.60897846109198,13.094961350033396L77.60895618624033,13.09565979884507L77.60894470393079,13.09601983740253L77.60928283100414,13.09603738908028L77.60998069535557,13.096073614189638L77.61051846223846,13.096101528875497L77.61052760339143,13.096261581060407L77.61056744964792,13.096959248020633L77.61058418764343,13.097252313103374L77.61061345095118,13.097656516430684L77.6106207017573,13.097756669153862L77.6103979656627,13.097785083579241L77.61036145154884,13.097788635382415L77.61044298590143,13.098115789736944L77.61047829671321,13.098257473401178L77.61048559953598,13.098289439629731L77.61055862776372,13.0985771356867L77.6106138993469,13.098793359701267L77.61072659268751,13.099234219273605L77.61079240183096,13.099468936948252L77.61085804349743,13.09970305729237L77.6104027701343,13.099721714103968L77.6097045522349,13.099750326627474L77.60921125696201,13.099770541552646L77.60925323318207,13.09997129463348L77.60929889083529,13.100189654326996L77.6088570700575,13.100221620555548L77.60886448846676,13.100253515451053L77.60902279706063,13.100934151404156L77.60903964062683,13.101006569056661L77.60905424627238,13.101446992650045L77.60917109143676,13.101532235926184L77.60920570506491,13.101513937344626L77.60950702128434,13.101354645767561L77.60971338805653,13.101647148567993L77.60976262008141,13.101716929691152L77.60978087713835,13.101773758541912L77.60991232794827,13.102189319513089L77.60989772230272,13.102203526725779L77.60982641642067,13.102269997398786L77.60972245455616,13.102366909671712L77.60955083822098,13.1025231890113L77.6094632043477,13.102601328681095L77.60931074188466,13.102741572097257L77.60912727450012,13.102910335557098L77.60912727450012,13.102952957195168L77.6088278587664,13.103084373912548L77.60886134936337,13.103156931763843L77.60890818981692,13.103258412268L77.60875848195006,13.103325896528276L77.60868545372233,13.103148306369652L77.6085247916213,13.103219342433102L77.60850653456437,13.103247756858481L77.60849400442903,13.103265056411008L77.60839334081139,13.10340403619807L77.6083896894,13.103443106032968L77.60838238657723,13.103556763734485L77.60837873516584,13.103673973239177L77.60837508375445,13.103713043074073L77.60835682669752,13.103848011594627L77.60834411645385,13.103928374449822L77.60834222105197,13.10394035847711L77.60833856964058,13.103979428312009L77.60832761540642,13.104075326997664L77.60826554141285,13.10406822339132L77.60825458717869,13.10415701847063L77.60830935834949,13.104160570273804L77.60830570693811,13.1041996401087L77.60829840411533,13.104306194203874L77.60821077024205,13.104299090597529L77.60812678778015,13.104291986991184L77.60812522877677,13.104317767061834L77.60812313636877,13.104352367645117L77.60811948495738,13.104419851905392L77.608115833546,13.104508646984705L77.60811948495738,13.104544165016428L77.60859121161623,13.104559681962122L77.60887532711443,13.104569027638636L77.60928981752484,13.104562964730789L77.60998854669369,13.104552744155226L77.61033224025775,13.104547716819601L77.61039066283993,13.104586786654497L77.61048919517106,13.10485398931028L77.6105111594157,13.104913552546364L77.61050020518154,13.104952622381262L77.61102629774419,13.105230014746315L77.61128160721829,13.105364631549266L77.61123048745888,13.105535118101544L77.61115410569415,13.105754388157248L77.61108077959202,13.105964886285411L77.61102965983261,13.106110510215483L77.61095298019349,13.10609275119962L77.61090186043407,13.106082095790104L77.61085439208604,13.106206408901139L77.61083310603749,13.10625989779555L77.6108105751494,13.106316514799484L77.61079962091524,13.106352032831209L77.6107558039786,13.106469242335901L77.61072294127612,13.10655448561204L77.61070833563058,13.106590003643765L77.61073754692167,13.10659710725011L77.61071928986473,13.106650384297696L77.61070468421919,13.10670010954211L77.61054767352955,13.10665393610087L77.61050518404718,13.106642742451974L77.610372405783,13.106607762659626L77.61028477190972,13.10658290003742L77.60987216242302,13.106472794139073L77.60983043033663,13.106461043342405L77.60973340879032,13.106433724304177L77.60960195798039,13.106401758075624L77.60941555298217,13.106825279212403L77.60913404719247,13.107464873929322L77.60910171462041,13.10753833509081L77.60917839425953,13.107573853122535L77.60927333095559,13.107666200005019L77.60931349648084,13.107705269839917L77.60944859870216,13.107840238360469L77.60955475961643,13.107952614881343L77.6095727466893,13.10797165507785L77.60960926080317,13.108010724912747L77.60961656362595,13.108017828519092L77.6096311692715,13.108035587534955L77.60971880314477,13.108127934417439L77.60975531725863,13.108152797039645L77.6099597962963,13.10829131736337L77.609985356176,13.108294869166544L77.61001091605571,13.108330387198269L77.61001821887848,13.108341042607785L77.6100401273468,13.108397871458545L77.610038853109,13.108421937978058L77.6100019056441,13.109119764458198L77.60996495817919,13.109817590938338L77.60995249347351,13.11005301173691L77.60989772230272,13.110049459933737L77.60985755677747,13.110045908130566L77.60983929972053,13.11019508386381L77.60975531725863,13.110184428454291L77.60974071161309,13.110184428454291L77.60972610596754,13.110276775336775L77.60975080953506,13.1102789598522L77.6097662714928,13.110280327139948L77.60976262008141,13.110319396974845L77.60975166584726,13.110418847463674L77.60952527834128,13.110386881235122L77.60953623257544,13.110489883527123L77.60961656362595,13.110539608771537L77.60971497917487,13.110603429327817L77.60973706020171,13.110617748441332L77.60973706020171,13.110649714669883L77.6098466025433,13.110649714669883L77.60988676806856,13.110646162866711L77.60991963077105,13.110646162866711L77.60996344770768,13.110646162866711L77.60996344770768,13.11073140614285L77.60996709911907,13.110855719253886L77.60996709911907,13.110887685482439L77.61003647593542,13.1109054444983L77.61010103139485,13.110982842280363L77.61019348662505,13.11109369006644L77.61022269791614,13.11112210449182L77.61025921203,13.11112210449182L77.610372405783,13.111374282517065L77.61045261846687,13.111558340387724L77.61051481082708,13.11170104840893L77.61058418764343,13.111864431354864L77.61066817010533,13.112052676923003L77.61072659268751,13.112184093640385L77.61073049650837,13.112199282948636L77.61079231809246,13.112439823468803L77.61079596950385,13.112454030681493L77.61085439208604,13.112677794281357L77.61100044854152,13.112809210998737L77.61100261807634,13.112816948953435L77.61101140277567,13.112848280833635L77.61104426547816,13.11295838673198L77.61123048745888,13.113444983766607L77.61123920282579,13.113474049882576L77.61128160721829,13.113615470318885L77.61145687496486,13.113604814909369L77.61146052637625,13.113626125728402L77.61152870070546,13.113973448321454L77.61166329730182,13.114659167409563L77.61175263928718,13.115114331257663L77.61170151952777,13.115121434864008L77.61176359352135,13.11518181551794L77.61177694284127,13.115277637034996L77.61186948445156,13.115941901396845L77.61187313586294,13.11596321221588L77.61187016294961,13.115968995844094L77.61184027316047,13.116027144672984L77.61189869574265,13.11629352991092L77.61195346691345,13.116552811542508L77.61201919231841,13.116591881377405L77.61202165493204,13.11661096501006L77.61211108928411,13.117304022300777L77.61212873466002,13.117440762335622L77.61204475219812,13.117430106926104L77.6119644211476,13.11742300331976L77.61191695279959,13.117419451516588L77.61176359352135,13.117405244303898L77.61178185057827,13.117540212824451L77.61178748425826,13.11759775279003L77.61178915340105,13.117614800691072L77.61179280481244,13.11762545610059L77.61179280481244,13.117636111510107L77.6118001076352,13.117689388557695L77.61180741045798,13.117774631833834L77.61182201610353,13.117874082322663L77.6118293189263,13.11794511838611L77.61183662174908,13.118023258055905L77.61184757598323,13.118094294119354L77.61185122739462,13.118136915757423L77.61186218162878,13.118218607230391L77.61186583304017,13.118257677065287L77.61186983312355,13.118291139352305L77.6118840900971,13.118410404601704L77.61179280481244,13.11842106001122L77.61181106186937,13.118577339350809L77.61180741045798,13.118602201973015L77.61184335428342,13.118904384783665L77.61185853021739,13.119031970156882L77.61189139291987,13.119319666213853L77.61192684155057,13.119598171559895L77.6119388612679,13.11969260554696L77.6119644211476,13.11992347275317L77.61200734770992,13.12029231346766L77.61200823808426,13.120299963889451L77.61205570643227,13.120665799616214L77.6120776149006,13.120875356003388L77.6121137607708,13.120980835503932L77.61211778042585,13.12099256550808L77.6123412761396,13.12164156513782L77.61236607640015,13.121713581552088L77.61174440133159,13.121748176298215L77.61104667688896,13.12178700301201L77.61077040962415,13.1218023766314L77.6108945576113,13.12206165826299L77.61095418900523,13.122182370719463L77.61102965983261,13.122335147107268L77.61122683604749,13.122750708078446L77.61125609307734,13.122812575288025L77.61139480097128,13.123105888395692L77.61155495972712,13.123444244205439L77.61162849130002,13.123599589036663L77.61214076101157,13.123476137494693L77.61243910462788,13.123404239862179L77.61282086747221,13.123315595359289L77.61300507339283,13.123272823144799L77.61350157420709,13.123157591398629L77.61404572563805,13.123031300529071L77.61418374192002,13.123006712381764L77.61487171340933,13.122884147535933L77.61555968489866,13.1227615826901L77.6160393962552,13.122676120211825L77.6160430476666,13.122676120211825L77.61604669907798,13.122704534637204L77.61609781883739,13.12287146938631L77.61610146961006,13.12287435472159L77.61615624141957,13.122917642827552L77.61677938670368,13.12283208629644L77.61747169582439,13.122737033716668L77.61768253137923,13.122708086440378L77.61770809125895,13.122704534637204L77.61773365113865,13.12280043332286L77.61777016525251,13.122970919875138L77.61778842230945,13.123041955938588L77.61780667936638,13.123120095608382L77.61781429611791,13.12315220115078L77.61781763360054,13.123166269049625L77.61782858783471,13.12321954609721L77.61785049630302,13.123311892979695L77.61787970759411,13.123429102484385L77.6178833590055,13.123453965106593L77.61751108835703,13.12356722949329L77.6168425432105,13.123770636225222L77.61628404081812,13.12394056214122L77.61617397636313,13.123973971548937L77.61550529937699,13.12417694445297L77.61525434280706,13.124253120820397L77.61536254980246,13.124676038015542L77.61553576500752,13.125353033882794L77.61565964947098,13.125837225035312L77.61570856275178,13.126030136079722L77.61586047709726,13.12662927714277L77.61578367172382,13.126654056326664L77.61511862225626,13.126868616614791L77.61445357278869,13.127083176902916L77.61439626113118,13.127101666964707L77.61431593008066,13.126849488939463L77.61395895695793,13.126960782247046L77.61346149981617,13.127115874177397L77.61328988348099,13.127162047618638L77.6132898883881,13.127162058088972L77.61358644154112,13.127794816446466L77.61388299469414,13.128427574803961L77.61408223975191,13.128852705928729L77.61417896027794,13.129060607523275L77.61447372277313,13.129694202017394L77.61476848526831,13.130327796511512L77.6150632477635,13.130961391005629L77.61512654340852,13.131097445533722L77.61535309784271,13.131597241500963L77.6156416045998,13.132233708909915L77.61588968838835,13.132781000237467L77.61579563224103,13.132808200072608L77.61575458616704,13.132820070072365L77.61569981499623,13.132862691710434L77.61511314008574,13.132862258563726L77.61441433636125,13.132861742631432L77.61371553263676,13.132861226699138L77.61301672891227,13.132860710766844L77.61231792518778,13.13286019483455L77.61161912146329,13.132859678902257L77.6109203177388,13.132859162969963L77.61022151401431,13.13285864703767L77.60952271028982,13.132858131105376L77.60882390656533,13.132857615173084L77.60812510284084,13.13285709924079L77.60742629911636,13.132856583308497L77.60672749539187,13.132856067376203L77.6060783459922,13.13285558810409L77.60605283817698,13.132812986405991L77.6058848211887,13.132532374015394L77.60552014229425,13.132604467087178L77.60483460572769,13.132739990249215L77.60430376005824,13.13284493269457L77.60414709787885,13.132862860757315L77.6034528252709,13.132942311732174L77.60275855266296,13.133021762707033L77.60206909628957,13.133100662522988L77.60206478470641,13.133098446638957L77.60144325889544,13.132779021251967L77.60082173308449,13.132459595864978L77.60065234867152,13.132372542872634L77.60038469155899,13.131940352586199L77.60010463696351,13.131488143882692L77.60009368272934,13.13147038486683L77.60005158842964,13.131330550435903L77.59985015664168,13.1306614075914L77.59970663312235,13.1301846321184L77.59968107324264,13.13012780326764L77.5996227827998,13.130002076479798L77.59959709078075,13.129946661305846L77.59902359973808,13.12966773802263L77.59839517954951,13.129362099382803L77.59809270928942,13.129214989852318L77.59791744154285,13.129147505592043L77.5979028358973,13.129126194773008L77.597783301759,13.12921482935448L77.59745736370812,13.129456512468046L77.59732226148681,13.129502685909289L77.597172009481,13.129504496657212L77.5964732563064,13.12951291761541L77.5957745031318,13.129521338573607L77.59525921405331,13.129527548531495L77.59507621106722,13.129540734515148L77.59447050919377,13.129584377382255L77.59437921000193,13.129590898293966L77.59368218170839,13.129640682523927L77.59342620553717,13.129658965248877L77.5929925152077,13.12957275609888L77.59230712131664,13.129436513206787L77.59162172742559,13.129300270314692L77.59124631293929,13.129225645261837L77.59099801696499,13.129275370506251L77.59096648413974,13.129329700948714L77.59061570538091,13.129934085903777L77.59026492662208,13.130538470858836L77.59018375222576,13.130678332759372L77.59017644940297,13.130749368822821L77.59041379114312,13.130944717997306L77.59032894414275,13.131078341927335L77.59010707258663,13.13142776322876L77.59002309012473,13.13156983535566L77.58996312715416,13.131673612354472L77.58961351841664,13.132278674865455L77.58946077277118,13.132543029424912L77.5893986987776,13.132717067780362L77.58935033462079,13.132920103288786L77.5892599451449,13.133299563500646L77.58921289359526,13.133604683586396L77.58910658586666,13.134294068388934L77.5891072121219,13.134295173922213L77.58920517397411,13.134468106744384L77.58881082154434,13.134393518877763L77.58882974873438,13.134296642642948L77.58896374407473,13.133610805810816L77.58896418082259,13.13360857037665L77.58826899576101,13.133565367377978L77.58764967272336,13.133526878903682L77.58757138724563,13.133526572670844L77.58687258867708,13.133523839148934L77.58617379010855,13.133521105627025L77.58547499154,13.133518372105115L77.58492571982886,13.133516223494166L77.58479425634951,13.13344497760441L77.58467012103179,13.13337770317044L77.58470663514565,13.133306667106991L77.58473584643674,13.133253390059403L77.58475775490507,13.133214320224507L77.58481982889865,13.13309000711347L77.58484173736696,13.1330473854754L77.58493667406302,13.132962142199261L77.58498049099965,13.132926624167537L77.58498149418432,13.132925766630136L77.58510098757542,13.132823621875536L77.58516671298038,13.132763241221605L77.58516671298038,13.132656687126431L77.58516671298038,13.132624720897878L77.58516671298038,13.132457786148773L77.58516671298038,13.132386750085324L77.58518694907605,13.132313637834006L77.58519227286008,13.13229440320284L77.58523243838535,13.132230470745736L77.58536023778387,13.132297955006013L77.5854784022393,13.13185461113676L77.58553915694182,13.131626664206419L77.5854113575433,13.131584042568349L77.58549561194802,13.131266862214911L77.58567501742377,13.130591480406734L77.58569251622006,13.130525605222957L77.58567060775175,13.130493638994404L77.58581141011393,13.129918739450257L77.58596637207407,13.129286025915768L77.58600815820405,13.12926367048897L77.58603940030181,13.129246956080872L77.58613798840925,13.129222093458663L77.5859882805424,13.128707081998657L77.58598124171326,13.128682710600156L77.58578734160933,13.128011346569807L77.58568156198591,13.127645092850093L77.58561296382935,13.127335009290944L77.58555741399876,13.127083907948844L77.58552820270766,13.126853040742635L77.58551654791161,13.126644442508981L77.58550994565073,13.126526274850768L77.58550629423935,13.12642682436194L77.58550994565073,13.126270545022352L77.58552398370689,13.12594623623598L77.58552455129627,13.12593312372097L77.58560625966291,13.125252330360068L77.58568953203437,13.12455850572538L77.5857728044058,13.123864681090692L77.58585607677726,13.123170856456005L77.58588604102357,13.122921194630724L77.58594486714655,13.12247772891083L77.58603675915647,13.12178499319639L77.58612865116639,13.121092257481951L77.5862073652256,13.120498864867109L77.58621955306972,13.120399395443275L77.58630454090422,13.11970577884923L77.58638952873872,13.119012162255185L77.58647451657323,13.118318545661142L77.58650678095931,13.118055224284458L77.5865645000598,13.117625570654733L77.58665754066139,13.116932988271184L77.58675058126299,13.116240405887636L77.58684362186457,13.115547823504087L77.58685366504105,13.115473063378081L77.58692989510497,13.114854369680161L77.58697051020543,13.114524731931034L77.587032584199,13.114535387340553L77.58715045143357,13.114255501843687L77.5872808801733,13.113945788013924L77.58742693662877,13.113686506382335L77.58747622483517,13.1136438898001L77.58785415176102,13.113317118852398L77.58789431728627,13.113331326065088L77.58803729509631,13.113267463963817L77.58860999391807,13.113011663779568L77.58868120060458,13.113004424299707L77.58937642068835,13.112933742288755L77.58990259354897,13.112880247062186L77.59000118165642,13.112848280833635L77.58998424275033,13.112784204298398L77.58993545625145,13.112599654611563L77.59002674153612,13.112571240186183L77.59004134718167,13.112564136579838L77.59013993528912,13.112500204122734L77.59024217480794,13.112432719862458L77.59025678045349,13.112425616256113L77.59032615726983,13.11237944281487L77.59034076291537,13.112368787405353L77.5903727671586,13.112347561595676L77.59042109396589,13.112315510357766L77.59051237925055,13.112255129703835L77.59053793913026,13.112240922491145L77.5906657385288,13.112155679215006L77.59079353792734,13.112077539545211L77.59087752038923,13.11221961167211L77.59090466666832,13.112199691548229L77.59108565083828,13.112066884135693L77.59150183404438,13.111839351952058L77.59208613755824,13.111519906447135L77.59210800970892,13.11149535780239L77.59232347929837,13.111253521209202L77.5923453877667,13.111235762193338L77.59257177527267,13.11097648056175L77.5925739070373,13.11097518677L77.59317129729327,13.110612623956634L77.59342620553717,13.11045791729857L77.59361913052068,13.110106807542772L77.59376578679614,13.109839903546563L77.59397026583379,13.109598380930835L77.59401435250945,13.109534271488629L77.59433175556109,13.109072714061313L77.59435748021781,13.10893647824945L77.59436461826355,13.108898675705861L77.59463482270618,13.108770810791654L77.59473706222501,13.108550598994961L77.59479285823143,13.108445927851315L77.59499266102208,13.10807110556668L77.59510479056792,13.10782104098431L77.59514236888893,13.107737236068468L77.59532128804689,13.10743533279881L77.59534336976765,13.107180265573943L77.59535049933798,13.107097911497426L77.59536145357214,13.106643280691351L77.5953724078063,13.106607762659626L77.59537605921768,13.106586451840592L77.59540159575718,13.106487092165759L77.59540892192017,13.106458586926383L77.59543083038848,13.106376895453417L77.59543813321126,13.106348481028038L77.5954819501479,13.10618154627893L77.59557725383463,13.105810730831365L77.5956170523692,13.105655879409408L77.59563530942614,13.105549325314234L77.59569373200833,13.10533976892706L77.59567141273637,13.10512767486098L77.5956462636603,13.104888689924158L77.59579962293854,13.104803446648019L77.59584343987518,13.10477858402581L77.59602236047238,13.104629859143893L77.59604426750145,13.104611649276706L77.59635463746933,13.104355919448288L77.59644227134261,13.104384333873668L77.59656641932976,13.104277779778494L77.59657878080857,13.104276443749002L77.59679645824713,13.104252917156288L77.59682566953822,13.104302642400702L77.59686218365208,13.104309746007047L77.59696077175953,13.104032705359595L77.59697172599368,13.103986531918352L77.59698268022785,13.103947462083456L77.59698424369866,13.103945021697402L77.59713969091747,13.103702387664557L77.59676359554464,13.103539004718623L77.59676306664774,13.103538732352717L77.59670152155107,13.10350703849007L77.59667961308274,13.103499934883725L77.59659563062085,13.103475072261519L77.59655911650698,13.103464416852002L77.59643861993122,13.10346086504883L77.59632542617824,13.103471520458346L77.59615746125445,13.103478624064692L77.59611729572919,13.103478624064692L77.59607893685939,13.103476847280698L77.59604061609006,13.103475072261519L77.59590186245737,13.10346086504883L77.59574120035636,13.10344665783614L77.59554037273008,13.103464416852002L77.59548560155929,13.103467968655174L77.59543448179987,13.103482175867864L77.59538734484244,13.10349920627301L77.59530668240134,13.103528349309105L77.59521174570529,13.103560315537658L77.59506568924981,13.10359228176621L77.59500726666762,13.103599385372554L77.59495979831959,13.1036064889789L77.59470450235186,13.103631322144274L77.59470419952252,13.103631351601107L77.59470419952252,13.103496383080554L77.59470419952252,13.103467968655174L77.59470785093391,13.103368518166345L77.5947115023453,13.103212238826757L77.5947115023453,13.103126995550618L77.5947115023453,13.103112788337928L77.59471396704531,13.102932978497076L77.59471515375668,13.102846403099994L77.59472245657946,13.10268302015406L77.59469324528837,13.10262263950013L77.59466038258589,13.102558707043025L77.59456909730122,13.102359806065367L77.59456179447844,13.102356254262196L77.59447917880492,13.10236089052968L77.59437192108633,13.102366909671712L77.59427333297889,13.10233494344316L77.59413823075758,13.102295873608263L77.59390088901745,13.102221285741642L77.59380718944576,13.102191524596792L77.5937219698595,13.102164456890883L77.59358686763818,13.102121835252813L77.59356130775848,13.102114731646468L77.59344081118272,13.102079213614743L77.59325824061338,13.102029488370329L77.59320346944259,13.102011729354466L77.59314526583313,13.101975095568221L77.59307932145543,13.101933589684672L77.59284928253807,13.101809276573636L77.593004218484,13.101484982260313L77.59330546595604,13.100854445289047L77.59360671342809,13.10022390831778L77.59366719868869,13.100097307444512L77.59344081118272,13.099866440238301L77.59333330810229,13.099657299310774L77.59333126884111,13.099653332047955L77.59326919484754,13.099511259921057L77.59310122992375,13.099148975997466L77.59304446188511,13.099021028509647L77.5929515220569,13.098811554696082L77.59280546560143,13.09841730454394L77.59278850729677,13.098371116604309L77.59254765629761,13.097715130546725L77.59233078212115,13.097124448189165L77.59235269058946,13.09710313737013L77.59238078807013,13.097076086689068L77.59288420572655,13.096591424358408L77.59306471580989,13.096417639357846L77.59338017492983,13.096099206384126L77.59364529022038,13.09583159183439L77.59386701115515,13.095597946597216L77.59403964265015,13.095416030863213L77.59433540697246,13.09511057579038L77.59434931042932,13.09512868853048L77.59477481281013,13.09568301211421L77.59520031519094,13.096237335697937L77.59535780216075,13.096442501980054L77.59551513777262,13.096031419765612L77.59567182354002,13.095622035447215L77.59578339979218,13.095386685032793L77.59608275521629,13.09475524759202L77.59638211064039,13.09412381015125L77.5966814660645,13.09349237271048L77.5969808214886,13.09286093526971L77.59701554293032,13.092787696515593L77.59689095450533,13.092182638962322L77.59675001939009,13.091498194512539L77.59660908427485,13.090813750062756L77.59651895098173,13.090376022161495L77.5964288328643,13.090140801827857L77.59617882594068,13.089488250335872L77.59592881901706,13.08883569884389L77.59586169693212,13.088660501229198L77.59565027879343,13.088195081033014L77.59536126632618,13.087558843101643Z"></path>
</svg>
```

This does not output my path correctly and whatever is displayed is extremely small. I have tried to follow all guides and look through previous answers, but I don't know what I am doing wrong here. When I pull this into Figma to see where the path is, it shows up with dimensions of `0.2x0.24`. Only after manually scaling it up and centering it in the viewbox frame in Figma do I see if it was rendered correctly. This is what it should look like:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your path is extremely small. The `stroke-width: 1px;` is so big that it covers all the shape. Please try `viewBox="77.555 13.06 .1 .1"` and stroke-width="0.001"

Comment: @enxaneta Oh my, it works! How did you figure the values out? Is it purely trial and error? Secondly, how do I make my path 'bigger'? This is just pulling shapes from a topojson

Comment: You can use the getBBox() method to get the size of the bounding box of the path.

Comment: @enxaneta And how did you apply that to the viewbox values?

Comment: The getBBox() returns the x y width and height of the bounding box. The viewBox attribute has 4 values: the x y width and height the view box. Use the bounding box values to build the new viewBox attribute. You may want to add some extra margin.

Answer (score 1):

You might also scale your geoData coordinates before rendering.
Some browsers (e.g safari) have problems rendering very tiny viewBox and stroke values.

Let's say you retrieve your data from a database or JSON API response.

You could split your `d` pathData to an array of point objects.

```
  function polyPathToPoints(attPts) {
    // split pathdata to array
    let coords = attPts.replace(/[\n\r\t]/g, "").replace(/[,MLZ]/gi, " ").split(' ').filter(Boolean);
    let points = [];
    // create array of point objects
    for (let i = 0; i < coords.length; i += 2) {
      points.push({
        x: +coords[i],
        y: +coords[i + 1]
      })
    }
    return points;
  }
```

You can skip this step if your data is already a point array.

Then you need to find the x/y extrema:

```
let xMin = Math.min(...points.map(pt=>{return pt.x}));
let xMax = Math.max(...points.map(pt=>{return pt.x}));
let yMin = Math.min(...points.map(pt=>{return pt.y}));
let yMax = Math.max(...points.map(pt=>{return pt.y}));
```

Now you can scale all coordinates and shift x and y according to extrema.

```
let pointsScaled = scalePolygon(points, scale, xMin, yMin, 3);

function scalePolygon(points, scale = 100, xOff=0, yOff=0, decimals = 8) {
  //round
    points = points.map((pt) => {
      return {
        x: +((pt.x-xOff) * scale).toFixed(decimals),
        y: +((pt.y-yOff) * scale).toFixed(decimals)
      };
    });
  return points;
}
```

The cropped and scaled viewBox values would be:

```
let scale = 1000;
let viewBoxW = (xMax-xMin)*scale
let viewBoxH = (yMax-yMin)*scale

svg.setAttribute('viewBox', `0 0 ${viewBoxW} ${viewBoxH}`);
```

### Example: scale polygon from data

```js
let points = polyPathToPoints(data);

/**
* find extrema to calculate viewBox
* and x/y offsets
*/
let xMin = Math.min(...points.map(pt=>{return pt.x}));
let xMax = Math.max(...points.map(pt=>{return pt.x}));
let yMin = Math.min(...points.map(pt=>{return pt.y}));
let yMax = Math.max(...points.map(pt=>{return pt.y}));

let scale = 1000;
let viewBoxW = (xMax-xMin)*scale
let viewBoxH = (yMax-yMin)*scale

// scale and shift coordinates
let pointsScaled = scalePolygon(points, scale, xMin, yMin, 3);

let d = pointsScaled
  .map((pt) => {
    return `${pt.x} ${pt.y}`;
  })
  .join(" ");


path.setAttribute("d", `M ${d} z`);
svg.setAttribute('viewBox', `0 0 ${viewBoxW.toFixed(1)} ${viewBoxH.toFixed(1)}`);


function scalePolygon(points, scale = 100, xOff=0, yOff=0, decimals = 8) {
  //round
    points = points.map((pt) => {
      return {
        x: +((pt.x-xOff) * scale).toFixed(decimals),
        y: +((pt.y-yOff) * scale).toFixed(decimals)
      };
    });
  return points;
}

  function polyPathToPoints(attPts) {
    // split pathdata to array
    let coords = attPts.replace(/[\n\r\t]/g, "").replace(/[,MLZ]/gi, " ").split(' ').filter(Boolean);
    let points = [];
    // create array of point objects
    for (let i = 0; i < coords.length; i += 2) {
      points.push({
        x: +coords[i],
        y: +coords[i + 1]
      })
    }
    return points;
  }
```

```css
svg{
  width:10em;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path id="path" d=""></path>
</svg>

<script>
let data = "M77.59517 13.08713 77.60399 13.0855 77.60426 13.08555 77.60423 13.08572 77.60323 13.08585 77.6032 13.08651 77.60411 13.08682 77.60413 13.08658 77.60559 13.08674 77.60556 13.08734 77.60571 13.08765 77.60702 13.08825 77.60867 13.08861 77.60714 13.09135 77.6061 13.09357 77.60606 13.09403 77.60803 13.09447 77.60821 13.09407 77.60901 13.09407 77.60894 13.09602 77.61052 13.0961 77.61062 13.09776 77.61036 13.09779 77.61086 13.0997 77.60921 13.09977 77.6093 13.10019 77.60886 13.10022 77.60905 13.10145 77.60917 13.10153 77.60951 13.10135 77.60991 13.10219 77.60883 13.10308 77.60891 13.10326 77.60852 13.10322 77.6083 13.10431 77.60813 13.10429 77.60812 13.10451 77.61033 13.10455 77.6105 13.10495 77.61128 13.10536 77.6107 13.1067 77.6096 13.1064 77.6091 13.10754 77.61004 13.1084 77.60995 13.11005 77.60974 13.11018 77.60975 13.11042 77.60953 13.11039 77.60954 13.11049 77.60996 13.11065 77.60997 13.11089 77.61026 13.11112 77.61128 13.11362 77.61146 13.1136 77.61213 13.11744 77.61176 13.11741 77.61179 13.11842 77.61208 13.12088 77.61237 13.12171 77.61077 13.1218 77.61163 13.1236 77.61604 13.12268 77.61616 13.12292 77.61771 13.1227 77.61788 13.12343 77.61525 13.12425 77.61586 13.12663 77.6144 13.1271 77.61432 13.12685 77.61329 13.12716 77.61589 13.13278 77.60608 13.13286 77.60588 13.13253 77.60207 13.1331 77.60065 13.13237 77.60009 13.13147 77.5996 13.12995 77.5979 13.12913 77.59732 13.1295 77.59343 13.12966 77.59125 13.12923 77.591 13.12928 77.59018 13.13068 77.59041 13.13094 77.5894 13.13272 77.58911 13.13429 77.58921 13.13447 77.58881 13.13439 77.58896 13.13361 77.58493 13.13352 77.58467 13.13338 77.58517 13.13276 77.58523 13.13223 77.58536 13.1323 77.58597 13.12929 77.58614 13.12922 77.58556 13.12708 77.58552 13.12593 77.58697 13.11452 77.58743 13.11369 77.58785 13.11332 77.58861 13.11301 77.59 13.11285 77.58994 13.1126 77.59209 13.11152 77.59257 13.11098 77.59343 13.11046 77.59436 13.1089 77.59463 13.10877 77.59532 13.10744 77.59569 13.10534 77.59565 13.10489 77.59635 13.10436 77.59686 13.10431 77.59714 13.1037 77.59644 13.10346 77.5947 13.10363 77.59472 13.10268 77.59457 13.10236 77.59285 13.10181 77.59367 13.1001 77.5931 13.09915 77.59233 13.09712 77.59434 13.09511 77.59536 13.09644 77.59702 13.09279 77.59652 13.09038 77.59536 13.08756 z"
</script>
```

I've simplified the polygon with the excellent [simplify.js](https://github.com/mourner/simplify-js) which is pretty handy for simplifying usually quite detailed geoData polygons.

Answer (score 0):

The shape was very small. I have now resized it and placed the path in the center of the viewBox.

```css
path {
  fill: #e3e3e3;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: #666;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
  <path d="M237.1,104l1.3-0.2l1-0.2l3.8-0.6l3.2-0.4l4.2-0.6l2.9-0.4l7.1-0.9l7.1-0.9l0.9-0.1l6.3-0.9l1.4-0.2l5.7-0.8l0.2,0l6.9-1 l7.1-1.1l4.1-0.6l3-0.5l0.5-0.1l0.7-0.1l4.1-0.6l1.6-0.5l4.4-1.3l2-0.5l0.3,0.3l0.2,0.2l1.8-1.4l0.7,0.2l3.6-0.4l4.6-0.5l2.5,0.4 l0.2,0l-0.3,1.5l-5.1,0.6l-5.1,0.6l-0.2,1.7l-0.2,4l1.3,0.4l0.2,0.1l0.9,0.2v0l1.4,0.4l0.5,0.1l2.3,0.6l2.7,0.7v0l0.3,0.1l0.2-2 l0.4,0.4l3.8,0.3l7.1,0.5l3.7,0.2l-0.2,1.9l-0.1,0.4l-0.1,0.7l-0.1,0.9v0.5l0.1,0.8l0.8,1.4l0.3,0.6l0.5,0.7l0.9,0.3l6.5,2.5 l6.1,2.3l0.5,0.1l1.3,0.2l1,0.2l4.8,0.7l1.3,0.2l0.9,0.1l4.8,1l2.4,0.5l-2.3,3.5l-3.5,5.2l-3.5,5.2l-3.5,5.2l-2.9,4.4l-0.5,0.9 l-3.1,5.4l-3.1,5.4l-3.1,5.4l-0.6,1.2l-0.3,0.6l-0.5,4v0l0.3,0.8l6,0.9l7.1,1l0.2,0l2.1,0.3l4.6,0.6l0.1-0.1l1.8-3.2h2.9h5.3 l-0.1,1.6l-0.2,6l-0.2,6l-0.1,3.1l3.5,0.2l7.1,0.3l5.6,0.2l0.1,1.4l0.4,6l0.2,2.5l0.3,3.5l0.1,0.9l-2.3,0.2l-0.4,0l0.9,2.8l0.4,1.2 l0.1,0.3l0.7,2.5l0.5,1.8l1.2,3.8l0.7,2l0.6,2l-4.6,0.2l-7.2,0.2l-5,0.2l0.4,1.7l0.5,1.9l-4.6,0.3l0.1,0.3l1.6,5.8l0.2,0.6l0.2,3.8 l1.2,0.7l0.4-0.2l3.1-1.4l2.1,2.5l0.5,0.6l0.2,0.5l1.3,3.6l-0.1,0.1l-0.8,0.6l-1,0.8l-1.8,1.3l-0.9,0.7l-1.6,1.2l-1.9,1.4v0.4 l-3.1,1.1l0.4,0.6l0.5,0.9l-1.6,0.6l-0.7-1.5l-1.6,0.6l-0.2,0.2l-0.1,0.1l-1.1,1.2v0.3l-0.1,1l-0.1,1v0.3l-0.2,1.2l-0.2,0.7v0.1 l-0.1,0.3l-0.1,0.8l-0.6-0.1l-0.2,0.8l0.5,0v0.3l-0.1,0.9l-0.9-0.1l-0.9-0.1v0.2v0.3l-0.1,0.6v0.8v0.3l4.9,0.1l3,0.1l4.2-0.1 l7.1-0.1l3.5,0l0.6,0.3l1,2.3l0.2,0.5l-0.2,0.3l5.4,2.4l2.7,1.2l-0.5,1.5l-0.8,1.9l-0.7,1.8l-0.5,1.3l-0.8-0.2l-0.5-0.1l-0.5,1.1 l-0.2,0.5l-0.2,0.5l-0.1,0.3l-0.5,1l-0.3,0.7l-0.2,0.3l0.3,0.1l-0.2,0.5l-0.2,0.4l-1.6-0.4l-0.5-0.1l-1.3-0.3l-0.9-0.2l-4.2-0.9 l-0.4-0.1l-1-0.2l-1.3-0.3l-2,3.6l-2.9,5.5l-0.3,0.6l0.8,0.3l1,0.8l0.4,0.3l1.4,1.2l1.1,1l0.2,0.2l0.4,0.3l0.1,0.1l0.2,0.2l0.9,0.8 l0.4,0.2l2.1,1.2l0.2,0l0.2,0.3l0.1,0.1l0.2,0.5v0.2l-0.4,6l-0.4,6l-0.1,2l-0.5,0l-0.5,0l-0.2,1.3l-0.9-0.1h-0.2l-0.2,0.8l0.2,0 l0.2,0v0.3l-0.2,0.9l-2.3-0.3l0.1,0.9l0.9,0.4l1,0.5l0.2,0.1v0.3h1.2l0.4,0h0.3h0.5v0.7l0.1,1.1v0.3l0.7,0.2l0.6,0.7l0.9,0.9 l0.3,0.2h0.4l1.2,2.2l0.8,1.6l0.6,1.2l0.7,1.4l0.9,1.6l0.6,1.1l0.1,0.1l0.6,2.1v0.1l0.6,1.9l1.5,1.1v0.1l0.1,0.3l0.4,0.9l1.9,4.2 l0.1,0.2l0.5,1.2l1.8-0.1v0.2l0.7,3l1.4,5.9l0.9,3.9l-0.5,0.1l0.6,0.5l0.2,0.8l0.9,5.7v0.2v0l-0.3,0.5l0.6,2.3l0.5,2.2l0.7,0.3v0.2 l0.9,5.9l0.2,1.2l-0.9-0.1l-0.9-0.1l-0.5,0l-1.6-0.1l0.2,1.2l0.1,0.5v0.1l0.1,0.1v0.1l0.1,0.5l0.1,0.7l0.2,0.9l0.1,0.6l0.1,0.7 l0.1,0.6l0.1,0.4l0.1,0.7v0.3l0.1,0.3l0.2,1l-0.9,0.1l0.2,1.3v0.2l0.4,2.6l0.2,1.1l0.3,2.5l0.3,2.4l0.2,0.8l0.2,2l0.5,3.2v0.1 l0.5,3.1l0.2,1.8l0.4,0.9l0.1,0.1l2.3,5.6l0.2,0.6l-6.4,0.3l-7.2,0.3l-2.8,0.1l1.3,2.2l0.6,1l0.8,1.3l2,3.6l0.3,0.5l1.4,2.5l1.6,2.9 l0.7,1.3l5.3-1.1l3.1-0.6l3.9-0.8l1.9-0.4l5.1-1l5.6-1.1l1.4-0.2l7.1-1.1l7.1-1l4.9-0.7l0,0v0.2l0.5,1.4l0.1,0l0.5,0.4l6.4-0.7 l7.1-0.8l2.2-0.2l0.2,0l0.3,0.8l0.3,1.5l0.2,0.6l0.2,0.7l0.1,0.3l0.1,0.1l0.1,0.5l0.2,0.8l0.3,1v0.2l-3.8,1l-6.8,1.7l-5.7,1.5 l-1.2,0.3l-6.8,1.7l-2.6,0.7l1.1,3.6l1.8,5.8l1.3,4.2l0.5,1.7l1.6,5.1l-0.8,0.2l-6.8,1.8l-6.8,1.8l-0.6,0.2l-0.8-2.2l-3.7,1 l-5.1,1.3l-1.8,0.4l0,0l3.1,5.4l3.1,5.4l2,3.6l1,1.8l3,5.4l3.1,5.4l3.1,5.4l0.6,1.2l2.4,4.3l2.9,5.5l2.6,4.7l-0.9,0.2l-0.5,0.1 l-0.5,0.4l-6,0h-7.1l-7.2,0h-7.2l-7.1,0l-7.2,0h-7.1l-7.2,0h-7.2l-7.1,0h-7.2l-7.1,0h-7.2l-6.7,0l-0.2-0.4l-1.7-2.4l-3.8,0.6 l-7.1,1.2l-5.5,0.9l-1.6,0.2l-7.1,0.7l-7.1,0.7l-7.1,0.7v0l-6.4-2.7l-6.4-2.7l-1.7-0.7l-2.7-3.7l-2.9-3.9l-0.2-0.1l-0.4-1.2l-2-5.7 l-1.5-4.1l-0.3-0.5l-0.5-1.1l-0.3-0.5l-5.9-2.4l-6.4-2.6l-3.1-1.3l-1.8-0.6l-0.2-0.2l-1.2,0.8l-3.4,2.1l-1.4,0.4l-1.5,0l-7.2,0.1 l-7.2,0.1l-5.3,0l-1.9,0.1l-6.3,0.4l-0.9,0.1l-7.1,0.4l-2.6,0.2l-4.5-0.7l-7.1-1.2l-7.1-1.2l-3.8-0.6l-2.6,0.4l-0.3,0.5l-3.6,5.2 l-3.6,5.2l-0.8,1.2l-0.1,0.6l2.4,1.7l-0.9,1.2l-2.3,3l-0.9,1.2l-0.6,0.9l-3.6,5.2l-1.6,2.3l-0.6,1.5l-0.5,1.7l-0.9,3.3l-0.5,2.6 l-1.1,5.9v0l1,1.5l-4-0.6l0.2-0.8l1.4-5.9v0l-7.1-0.4l-6.4-0.3h-0.8l-7.1,0l-7.2,0l-7.2,0l-5.7,0l-1.3-0.6l-1.3-0.6l0.4-0.6l0.2-0.5 l0.2-0.3l0.7-1.1l0.2-0.4l1-0.7l0.5-0.3v0l1.2-0.9l0.7-0.5v-0.9v-0.3v-1.4v-0.6l0.2-0.6v-0.2l0.5-0.5l1.3,0.6l1.3-3.8l0.6-2 l-1.3-0.4l0.9-2.7l1.9-5.8l0.2-0.6l-0.2-0.3l1.4-4.9l1.6-5.4l0.4-0.2l0.3-0.1l1-0.2l-1.5-4.4l-0.1-0.2l-2-5.8l-1.1-3.1l-0.7-2.7 l-0.5-2.2l-0.3-2l-0.1-1.8l-0.1-1l-0.1-0.9l0.1-1.3l0.2-2.8v-0.1l0.9-5.8l0.8-6l0.9-5.9l0.9-6l0.3-2.1l0.6-3.8l0.9-5.9l0.9-5.9 l0.8-5.1l0.2-0.9l0.9-5.9l0.9-6l0.9-5.9l0.4-2.3l0.5-3.7l0.9-5.9l1-5.9l0.9-5.9l0.1-0.6l0.8-5.3l0.4-2.8l0.7,0.1l1.2-2.4l1.3-2.7 l1.5-2.2l0.5-0.4l3.8-2.8l0.4,0.1l1.5-0.5l5.9-2.2l0.8-0.1l7.1-0.6l5.4-0.5l1-0.3l-0.2-0.5l-0.5-1.6l0.9-0.2l0.2-0.1l1-0.5l1-0.6 l0.2-0.1l0.7-0.4l0.2-0.1l0.3-0.2l0.5-0.3l0.9-0.5l0.2-0.1l1.3-0.7l1.3-0.7l0.9,1.2l0.3-0.2l1.9-1.1l4.2-2l6-2.7l0.2-0.2l2.2-2.1 l0.2-0.2l2.4-2.2v0l6.1-3.1l2.7-1.3l2-3l1.5-2.3l2.1-2.1l0.5-0.5l3.2-4l0.3-1.2l0.1-0.3l2.7-1.1l1-1.9l0.6-0.9l2-3.2l1.2-2.1 l0.4-0.7l1.8-2.6l0.2-2.2l0.1-0.7l0.1-3.9l0.2-0.3v-0.2l0.2-0.9l0.1-0.2l0.2-0.7l0.1-0.2l0.5-1.4l1-3.2l0.4-1.3l0.2-0.9l0.6-1.8 l-0.2-1.8l-0.2-2l1.6-0.7l0.4-0.2l1.9-1.3l0.2-0.2l3.1-2.2l0.9,0.2l1.3-0.9l0.2,0l2.2-0.2l0.3,0.4l0.4,0.1l1-2.4l0.1-0.4l0.2-0.3v0 l1.6-2.1l-3.8-1.4v0l-0.6-0.3l-0.2-0.1l-0.9-0.2l-0.4-0.1l-1.3,0l-1.1,0.1l-1.7,0.1h-0.5l-0.4,0l-0.4,0l-1.4-0.1L243,244l-2,0.1 l-0.6,0l-0.5,0.1l-0.5,0.1l-0.9,0.2l-0.9,0.3l-1.6,0.3l-0.5,0.1l-0.5,0.1l-2.7,0.2l0,0v-1.2v-0.2l0.1-0.9v-1.3v-0.7v-0.1v-1.5 l0.1-0.7v-1.4l-0.2-0.5l-0.4-0.5l-0.9-1.7l-0.1,0l-0.8,0l-1.1,0l-1-0.3l-1.4-0.3l-2.4-0.6l-1-0.3l-0.9-0.2l-1.3-0.4l-0.3-0.1 l-1.3-0.3l-1.8-0.4l-0.6-0.2l-0.5-0.3l-0.7-0.4l-2.4-1.1l1.6-2.8l3.1-5.4l3.1-5.4l0.6-1.1l-2.4-2l-1.1-1.8v0l-0.6-1.2l-1.7-3.1 l-0.5-1.1l-1-1.8l-1.5-3.4l-0.2-0.4l-2.5-5.6l-2.2-5.1l0.2-0.2l0.3-0.2l5.2-4.2l1.8-1.5l3.3-2.7l2.7-2.3l2.3-2l1.8-1.6l3.1-2.6 l0.2,0.2l4.3,4.8l4.4,4.8l1.6,1.8l1.6-3.5l1.6-3.5l1.2-2l3.1-5.4l3.1-5.4l3.1-5.4l3.1-5.4l0.4-0.6l-1.3-5.2l-1.5-5.9l-1.4-5.9 l-0.9-3.8l-0.9-2l-2.6-5.6l-2.5-5.6l-0.7-1.5l-2.2-4l-3-5.5L237.1,104z" stroke="#666666" stroke-width="1" fill="#e3e3e3"/>
</svg>
```