# how to get SVG titles when using viewBoxes for longitude/latitude coordinates

Tags: svg

I'm trying to create an SVG containing landmarks that are defined using longitude/latitude (it doesn't matter if they are flipped). But every landmark has a nested `title` element, and I expect that on mouse-over a tooltip appears containing that title entry.

Here's a very much reduced example of what I have, which is just following along the examples as defined in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="41.92510369301815 -73.38857966919343 0.004943773525909023 0.010611880004319119">
  <rect width="0.0001" height="0.0001" x="41.92865062754184" y="-73.38096767127567"><title>0.002437043</title></rect>
  <rect width="0.0001" height="0.0001" x="41.928647149048246" y="-73.38095714784605"><title>0.002843217</title></rect>
</svg>
```

In reality I have hundreds / thousands of `rect` entries, and when viewed from a distance they are actually defining trails.

The problem I have is that when loading this into Firefox, although the rects render (albeit a bit fuzzier than you might expect) the mouseover `title` text never appears.

Am I hitting some decimal rounding problems here? Because if I scale everything manually by 10000 then the tooltips come up.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="419251.0369301815 -733885.7966919343 49.43773525909023 106.11880004319119">
  <rect width="1" height="1" x="419286.5062754184" y="-733809.6767127567"><title>0.002437043</title></rect>
  <rect width="1" height="1" x="419286.47149048245" y="-733809.5714784604"><title>0.002843217</title></rect>
  <rect width="1" height="1" x="419286.4366962671" y="-733809.4655931061"><title>0.0032493907</title></rect>
  <rect width="1" height="1" x="419286.40189653775" y="-733809.3597362792"><title>0.0036555645</title></rect>
  <rect width="1" height="1" x="419286.36709271686" y="-733809.2544448508"><title>0.0040617385</title></rect>
</svg>
```

of course, now I may as well just manually edit the x/y values so that I don't even need the viewBox.

Am I holding it wrong?

And/or is there a more idiomatic way to plot shapes using lat/long coordinates?

(For anybody who is wondering what exactly this data is, it's simracing track data for "percentage travelled around the track" at a variety of sample points, and the audience of the image should be able to mouse over any part of the track and see how far around the track that data point is)

Comment: Yes, rounding problems like this are known. You might be able to do a systematic hit test if you loop through a grid of screen coordinates (only integers!), transform them to userspace coordinates with the matrix element[.getScreenCTM()](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/types.html#__svg__SVGGraphicsElement__getScreenCTM).invert() and then test element[.isPointInFill()](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/types.html#__svg__SVGGeometryElement__isPointInFill).

Comment: You can also circumvent this problem by scaling your geodata coordinates beforehand. See ["Path does not fill SVG viewbox"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76549162/path-does-not-fill-svg-viewbox/76551954#76551954)